# Fetch data from 1 table and all related data

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 contains users names.
Table 2 contains users adress.

How to query the database (using PHP) for the users name AND their adress in a single query?

I've tried using INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, but I think I have a syntax error.

table 1:

| id (PK) | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

table 2:

| id (FK) | adress |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Street 1 |

Comment: Use JOIN statement, you'll find it in MySQL documentation. That are basics.

Comment: Post the query that you tried.

Comment: How any record from users table is connected with addresses? Have you some field for it, MM table, anything else? Without relations data can not be connected.

Comment: SELECT table1.name, table1.id, table2.id, table2.adress
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table.id=table2.id;

Answer (score 0):

based on your question you could connect to your database, then

```
<?php

    //.. database connection


    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT table1.name, table1.id, table2.id, table2.adress FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table.id=table2.id");

    $sql->execute();

    $res = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($res);
?>
```